# how to read from file that was giving in a command line argument in java?

Tags: java

I want to read from file , where the program gets the file name ( the file is also a java file) from command line argument , and then prints only the comments from the file
i want to read from the file using `java.nio.file.Files` and  `java.nio.file.Path`  maybe.
i am supposed to read the file name using the main function
i don't know how to do that , any help plz ?
this is actually my first ever code i write in java so i am having a lot of difficulties
here is what i have so far :

```
package firtJavaCode;

import java.io.*; 
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import java.lang.String ;

public class ReadFromFile {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            //String filePath = "";   // here is my problem i don't know how to read from a giving file
            String line;
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));
            int lineNumber = 0;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                lineNumber++;
                if  (line.contains("//")) {
                     StringTokenizer st1 =  new StringTokenizer(line, "//");            
                     System.out.println(st1.nextToken()); 
                }
                
                // i still didn't complete the code , just want to figure how to read from file first
            }
        }catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A quickie on how to [access command line arguments in Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/cmdLineArgs.html).

Comment: Command line arguments are passed to the `main()` method in `args` parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the arguments which are written in the console in the String[] args array.
To get the filename we assume that you execute the program like this: `java example /home/file.txt`.

```
args[0] == "/home/file.txt"
```

So the filepath is saved in `args[0]` as a string already so you won't need the extra `String filepath` in the code.

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(args[0]));
```

So basically the arguments that you put in after the program name are saved all in the `String args[]` array.

I also would implement a way to check if only the filepath is entered and not some other crap like this:

```
if (args.length() > 0)
{
    System.out.println("Error! Too many arguments entered!");
}
```

Comment: `args[0] = "/home/file.txt"` line is missleading, it would seem that OP has to assign that value in code. If anything, change it to equality, `args[0] == "/home/file.txt"`

Comment: already did thanks for the advice I overlooked the error.

Comment: i am using eclipse , how can i execute the code using eclipse and not console

Comment: Go to the "Run" Tab -> Run Configurations -> Arguments and input the file path. Here is a picture tutorial https://imgur.com/a/qAYjFv0

Comment: i keep getting Access is denied , i tried putting the file in the same working space of my code but i still get the same mistake

Comment: Did you hardcode it? maybe the file is opened in another program?